# How to write ElasticsearchSink for Spark Structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark structured streaming to process high volume data from Kafka queue and doing some heaving ML computation but I need to write the result to Elasticsearch.

I tried using the `ForeachWriter` but can't get a `SparkContext` inside it, the other option probably is to do `HTTP Post` inside the `ForeachWriter`.

Right now, am thinking of writing my own ElasticsearchSink.

Is there any documentation out there to create a Sink for Spark Structured streaming ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [ForeachSink](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/eff7b40890f39617538d300df747277781a6f014/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/ForeachSink.scala#L31). It shows how to implement a Sink and convert DataFrame to RDD (it's very tricky and has a large comment). However, please be aware that the Sink API is still private and immature, it might be changed in future.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Spark 2.2+ and ES 6.x then there is a ES sink out of the box:

```
df
  .writeStream
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") 
  .option("es.mapping.id", "mappingId")
  .start("index/type") // index/type
```

If you are using ES 5.x like I was you need to implement an `EsSink` and an `EsSinkProvider`:

EsSinkProvider:

```
class EsSinkProvider extends StreamSinkProvider with DataSourceRegister {

  override def createSink(sqlContext: SQLContext,
                          parameters: Map[String, String],
                          partitionColumns: Seq[String],
                          outputMode: OutputMode): Sink = {

    EsSink(sqlContext, parameters, partitionColumns, outputMode)
  }

  override def shortName(): String = "my-es-sink"
}
```

EsSink:

```
case class ElasticSearchSink(sqlContext: SQLContext,
                             options: Map[String, String],
                             partitionColumns: Seq[String],
                             outputMode: OutputMode)
  extends Sink {


  override def addBatch(batchId: Long, df: DataFrame): Unit = synchronized {
    val schema = data.schema
    // this ensures that the same query plan will be used
    val rdd: RDD[String] = df.queryExecution.toRdd.mapPartitions { rows =>
      val converter = CatalystTypeConverters.createToScalaConverter(schema)
      rows.map(converter(_).asInstanceOf[Row]).map(_.getAs[String](0))
    }

    // from org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd library
    EsSpark.saveJsonToEs(rdd, "index/type", Map("es.mapping.id" -> "mappingId"))
  }
}
```

And then lastly, when writing the stream use this provider class as the `format`:

```
df
  .writeStream
  .queryName("ES-Writer")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
  .format("path.to.EsProvider")
  .start()
```