# Spark Structured Streaming integrate with ElasticSearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-structured-streaming

I'm building an App which send some data to my cluster.
I store this data into a specific HDFS folder, where a Spark Streaming application is running.

In this streamApp, I'll do some fast & cheap datascience.
After, I have to index results to ElasticSearch to serve my AngularApp with data.

Everything is working fine,

BUT ... I can't index my results with ES.
The fact is ... that I can't tranform my results DataFrame to RDD because it use some Dataframe Stream as input

Here my pseudo-code :

```scala
val schema = StructType(
    StructField("id", StringType, nullable = false) ::
    StructField("code", StringType, nullable = false) :: Nil)


val lines = spark.readStream
  .format("json")
  .schema(schema)
  .load(HDFSPath)

// Do some basics stuff here

import spark.implicits._

val linesRDD = lines.rdd.map(row => 
        StreamingObj(row(0).toString,row(1).toString))  // RDD[StreamingObj]
linesRDD.saveToEs("stream/stream")           // ES
val linesDF= linesRDD.toDF()

val queryNode = linesDF
    .writeStream
    .format("console")
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(4.seconds))
    .start
```

And It fail when I try to transform my DataFrame to RDD.

I have to transform to RDD to be able to index data.

On lines.rdd.map , I got this.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
```

Is it possible to index DataStreaming spark inside ES ?

Thanks for your help.

Try more simple case :

```scala
   val lines = spark.readStream
      .format("json")
      .schema(schema)
      .load(HDFSPATH).as[StreamingObj]

  lines.writeStream
      .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start("index/stream")
```

> 17/12/21 15:37:55 INFO util.Version: Elasticsearch Hadoop v5.4.2
>   [a478aabe9e] Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source
>   org.elasticsearch.spark.sql does not support streamed writing

I do same thing as docs => https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-sql-streaming

or even this example : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/spark-structured-streaming-sink-in-append-mode/105664/4

or this one :

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/structured-streaming-failed-to-find-data-source-es/112144

Here my Maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Is it the good one ? I can't use format('es') , it densest find it.

Seems that Spark Structured streaming in ES is only > 6.0

See https://www.elastic.co/blog/structured-streaming-elasticsearch-for-hadoop-6-0

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here

```
val linesRDD = lines.rdd.map(row => 
        StreamingObj(row(0).toString,row(1).toString))  // RDD[StreamingObj]
```

Conversions to `RDD` are not allowed in structured streaming queries. You can either try to write directly:

```
lines
  .writeStream
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  ...
```

or use `ForeachWriter`:

```
lines.writeStream.foreach(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

For implementing this in Elasticsearch `5.x`, you need to implement a CustomSink and CustomSinkProvider like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50448963/3213111).

Then in the `lines.writeStream.foreach(...)` you can specify the provider within the `format`.